# Showing z scale with shaded relief instead of colour scale?

Tags: arcgis-pro, scale, shaded-relief

I've got a .flt file with a z value (height), when displayed this gives me a scale based on the z value.

To better visualize the data I want to apply a shaded relief function to the data, but when I do this the scale is based on colour range (0-255), but I need it to show the scale as the z value.

Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS Pro, failing that, is there a way to do this in QGIS that I could then export to ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Have you tried the Hillshade function?

Comment: Yes, same issue unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

Hillshade and Elevation are two different type of data. Elevation is the altitude value and hill shade is calculated from altitude variation with a setting of azimuth and vertical angle.

You need to calculate your hillshade and then use it for your project. To do so there is a tool called `hillshade` in QGIS. You could find it with searchbox.

[image]

You have to use your elevation data as input and choose the vertical angle and azimuth to get the hillshade. Then you have to set the style to be between white for 0 and black for your max value.

If hillshade is not the result you want then you can use you can use slope calculation. It will be like a kind of texture in your map based on elevation.

I think there is the same kind of tool in ArcGis pro.

Comment: This is not what I need- the 0 (white)- 255 (black) is exactly what I said I didn't want in my question above...Hillshade and shaded relief both have this output. I need the symbology key to show the z value data and NOT the 0-255 scale.

Comment: The hillshade raster doesn't contain elevation. You have to activate both elevation layer and hillshade. Then you just turn off the legend for hillshade.

Comment: Yes this is what I've been doing, but I was hoping for a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Unfrotunatly there is no other way. You can check the raw data if you save it as textual format, there is no elevation. You can merge the two raster in a multichannel raster with one channel for elevation, one for hillshade but the style will be more complicate to handle. As an alternative, you could calculate the contourline, it can give information on elevation and give some texture.

Comment: I agree with @CorentinLemaitre hill shade is recording direction of light and elevation is well elevation. I would simply overlay the DEM with transparency set to 50% to allow the hill shading effect. In ArcPro 2.9 you can now play around with the layer blend to improve the visual effect, but it is only the DEM that you have in your layout legend which will be showing your range of Z.